# TestFx - Method Start is not called when extending ApplicationTest

Tags: java, maven, javafx, testfx

I was updating my application from JDK 8 to 13 and to Javafx 13.
Updated all dependencies to the latest updated ones.
But now one of my tests returns error.
The `public void start(Stage stage)` is not called on initialization, but on After the function `public void tearDown()` is called, closing a null application.

I can't understand why the start is not being called.

```
public class AppUiChooseDownloadFolderTestIT extends BaseUiTestIT {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Starting test case {}", testname.getMethodName());
    }

    @Override
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```

```
public class BaseUiTestIT extends ApplicationTest {
    protected App app;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        app = Mockito.mock(App.class);

        Injector.injectMembers(BaseUiTestIT.class, this);
        Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(app).start(Mockito.any());

        app.start(stage);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        LOG.info("Stopping application {}", app);

        if (app != null)
         app.stop();

        closeWindows();
        LOG.info("Cleanup of app finished");
    }
}
```

Specifications

- Version: 4.0.15-alpha
- OpenJDK 13
- JavaFX 13
- Platform: Ubuntu

Comment: Please mention what JUnit you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using `testfx-junit5` and not `testfx-junit` if you are using JUnit 5.